# php get method unreachable in xampp

Tags: php, backbone.js, xampp, slim

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but haven't been able to get anywhere. There are so many questions asked in stackoverflow, and I've tried almost all of them, but still haven't been able to figure out what the problem is that I'm having.

I'm working on a project for my Master's thesis for which I have to perform some data analysis. I'm building a site using php, backbone, and mongodb. I'm using xampp, and this is my directory structure:

```
htdocs
     |-MyProject
            |------API
                    |---Slim
                    |---index.php

            |------scripts
                    |-------App
                             |----Collections
                             |----Models
                             |----Views
                    |-------lib
      |-index.html
```

The index.html is the boilerplate html stuff and calls backbone collections and views. The index.php within the directory API instantiates slim and has GET method.

Here's the index.php

```
<?php
echo 'test';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

use Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/trends', 'getTrends');
```

and my backbone collections

```
App.Collections.TrendsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Models.TrendModel,
    url : "API/trends", 

    initialize: function(){
        console.log('collections');
    }


});
```

I read that I may need to set RewriteRule, so I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /API/index.php [R,NC]
```

but this didn't find the method I'm trying to reach either. I've been trying to figure this out for too long, and I'm pressing for time. Can someone please give me some guidance?

EDIT:

```
function getTrends(){
    echo 'Hello';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying to figure it out, I finally realized that the rewrite rules should be in .htaccess in the same directory as index.php. It finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in `getTrends` function. Show me that function.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have anything in the getTrends(). Should it still not show the text?

Comment: I just realized that if I use the full URL `http://localhost:81/MyProject/API/index.php/trends`, then it shows the text, but why is Backbone not finding it?

Comment: Where is your model??

Comment: I already figured out. Apparently, I just had to include RewriteRule in .htaccess and save it in the root directory of index.php. Thanks for trying to help :)